# Getting undefined ID after using createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm getting undefined ID after using createUserWithEmailAndPassword function.

Here is the code:

```
return async (dispatch) => {
                    dispatch({ type: ATTEMPTING });
                    if(name && email && password)
                    {
                        try {
                         await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                         .then(user => handleAccountCreated(dispatch, user.uid, name,email,radio))
                        .catch(error => handleError(dispatch, error.message));
                    }catch(e) {
                        handleError(dispatch, e.message);
                    }
                    }else{
                        handleError(dispatch, "There is an error in your data");
                    }


                 }

const handleAccountCreated = (dispatch, userId, name,email , radio) => {
        const ip = '223';
    firebase.database().ref(`mydatabase/${userId}`)
    .set({ name ,email,ip,radio})
    .then(() => { dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS }); })
    .catch(error => handleError(dispatch, error.message));

 }
```

I have already tried with :

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

        .then(firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => handleAccountCreated(dispatch, user.uid, name, email ,radio)))
```

the same issue

Comment: Update your handleAccountCreated call to handleAccountCreated(dispatch, user.user.uid, name, email, radio)

Comment: thanks @juicy89 it worked